# Can I list freelancing as work experience?

Tags: resume, job-search, work-experience, freelancing

For last 3 years I've been freelancing as a game programmer starting from ground up on individual's projects all the way up to current full time independent contractor at a fairly well known game company.

I also have some applications published on other platforms like android that I did independently along with few other projects.

Although I do have all the projects at my disposal ,like all the files , videos and builds, not every client would be available/valuable enough for testimonials.

Can I list all this as work experience on my resume and
How should I highlight this with as much weight as possible?
Can I list it as 3 years of continuous work experience disregarding any breaks?

Comment: I'm assuming you got paid for this work, right? If you do the work and you get paid for it, it's clearly professional experience.

Comment: @Erik yes I did get paid. Is there a requirement to list it as such? I have invoices as proof as well if needed

Comment: @Erik I agree getting paid is good, but what if i had done volunteering projects to help associations build websites and application. Doesnt take also count as work-experience?

Comment: @Smit: then it counts as volunteer work experience, not professional work experience. Can still go on a resume, but usually ranked lower by recruiters.

Comment: @Allahjane I've removed the link to your resume. We cannot give advice on individual resumes as Q&A should be useful to more than just the author of the question. Check [tour] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Looks like we have a few related questions on this topic but this seems to be the first post to ask the general question of whether and how to list freelance work on a resume. Since this will likely be a canonical question, comprehensive answers are preferred.

Comment: The question is answered but the net solution is by adding more than one answers covering specific parts of the question , I'd have to select the best among all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I list freelancing as work experience?

Why not? In fact this can distinguish you from your peers. If you think what you have done as a freelancer has added value to you and your skills go ahead and added with confidence.

I have came across big companies that asked me if I have done any freelance work or contributed to any opensource application aside from my full time job.

> Can I list all this as work experience on my resume and How should I
>   highlight this with as much weight as possible? Can I list it as 3
>   years of continuous work experience disregarding any breaks?

Perhaps you can have a new section in your profile where you list all the projects you have done. Try to point out the top 3 and not anything more than that. If you do so it's going to be to wordy and look less valuable. Remember Quality is more important than the Quantity.

Comment: As you might've guessed I haven't been doing a full time company job until recently and many companies forbid working outside of your job in terms anyway so I wonder if having freelancing as only job for 2 years look bad?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. And You should.

> What is Resume?  In simple words, a collection of your talent, skills and
>   experience.

Based on the information provided, you seem to have a great skill of hustling between projects and prioritising it. So I can actually hire you as a Product Manager, game developer or the Tech-Lead of Game and Design.

Bang, with that information if i can derive with a suggestion then why not your future recruiters.

> Can I list it as 3 years of continous work experience disregarding
>   any breaks? Work matter, not breaks. Everyone needs timeoff. So you dont have too mention until it was exceeding 1.5months.

You dont have list all the projects, priortize it. According to you which is your best work. Do take note if you pick 3, make sure to have at least one latest.

Lastly, Freelancing is a skill not everyone has it!

Answer (score 0):

The point of a resume is to get your possible future employer to want to meet you.

As long as it is in adequacy with the job offer then there's no reason it shouldn't be in your resume. Even more if you learned a lot and ended up working with a known company !

Be carefull though to keep your resume clear and readable , recruiters see a lot of resume and don't have much time to spend on it.
You must adapt your experience to what the company wants. That's the important point.

The breaks don't realy matter as long as it's not 2 years of break on 3 years of freelancing.
To highlight it you can develop this part more than the others but be carefull , don't overload you resume.

Comment: How exactly would I list any breaks or inversely say how'd I show that I didn't had any major breaks given that resume space is too limited to list all projects and durations

Comment: @Allahjane FYI: I guess my answer, answers your question.

Comment: As i said , as long as there's no major break you don't need to speak about it , and even when there is one don't put it on your resume. Explain it on your motivation letter if you feel the need (or the use) and be ready to answer it clearly if the recruiter ask about it.